# Pull Twitter texts without account

Tags: python, twitter

Without having a twitter-account I can search tweets, e.g. with the URL https://twitter.com/search?q=stackoverflow or https://twitter.com/StackOverflow or https://twitter.com/hashtag/stackoverflow.

To access twitter using Python, there are several API wrappers, maybe the most famous ones being [tweepy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy) and [twitter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter).

It does not seem to be possible to access tweets without authentication.

How can I access tweets from Python without logging in to twitter?

ps. I know that I can download the page and parse the html, but this looks like a last resort rather than an elegant solution.

Comment: Why not create an account?

Comment: @WayneWerner: short answer: Why create an account? (I know this is not an answer). I want to access text that they make accessible for the non-registered public. Nothing else. One more reason is: I want to use this as an example for my students and not force them to create accounts.

Comment: Would you want to teach your students to take the steps to properly sign up for an API? That seems useful to me. Give them a random character generator to create their twitter bot name, if that's something that you worry about. If you're teaching at a university, I'm sure they have an email address for the students (otherwise they could create a throw-away free webmail address if they don't want to use their own).

Comment: If you're just interested in twitter-like activity, you could probably knock something together pretty easily or use something like [Firefeed](https://firefeed.io/) (I just searched for 'open source twitter clone')

Comment: @WayneWerner: I thought of creating a random acount for them and passing the credentials, but I consider that dangerous for me having created the account, while the one crazy student does something else than homework. Maybe I am too paranoid. Having them create their own random account could be a solution. Thank you for the link to Firefeed. "Real" data would be nice though...

Comment: If you use Firefeed you could either have your students generate random "tweets" for you, or just create some [markov bots](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/06/generating-pseudo-random-text-with-markov-chains-u/)

Comment: @WayneWerner: Man this last link to the markov bots blew my mind O_o This semester there are going to be some fun homeworks. At least for me :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

> Authentication on all endpoints
>
> We require applications to
> authenticate all of their requests with OAuth 1.0a or Application-only
> authentication. This visibility allows us to prevent abusive behavior,
> and it also helps us to further understand how categories of
> applications are using the API. We apply this understanding to better
> meet the needs of developers as we continue to evolve the platform.

They need to apply rate limiting (and may be other security precautions) to minimize abuse, so, they do not allow public access to APIs.

Searching tweets using Twitter's website is manual. So there are less chances of abuse. Moreover, even if you try to parse it from web, most probably they will ban your IP address as soon as you start sending more requests than they think are not abusive.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to create an account? Keep in mind different circumstances.

1. **accounts are occassionally very hard to create**. For instance, it has been reported that Twitter doesn't support phone numbers from certain locations. What would you do if you cannot authenticate with your personal mobile?
2. **account features are heavily limited**. For instance, under the standard dev account you will not retrieve past data for your educational project (e.g. a sentiment analysis of celebrities tweets).
3. **accounts will not be free** [Twitter has just decided to discontinue supporting free accounts](https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/1621026986784337922?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1621041696715964417%7Ctwgr%5Eb1b92d1dcbf11a206800a8d0f0346cf8a52e78d6%7Ctwcon%5Es3_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2023%2F02%2F01%2Ftwitter-to-end-free-access-to-its-api%2F)